# Site is not sending any email

Tags: 7, emails

I have setup web in Drupal 7 and I am using `webform` module to create/configure the forms. The web is not sending any email including registration emails.

I tried to use the following php script to debug the root issue but couldn't-

```
<?php
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
   echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
}
else {
   echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
}
?>
```

The script show me successful message. I tried to check the logs at admin/reports/dblog but can't see any error log.

Since I am behind this proxy. Hence I have set the proxy in sites/default/settings.php file as following-

```
$conf['proxy_server'] = '192.168.68.10';
$conf['proxy_port'] = 3128;
$conf['proxy_username'] = 'myuser';
$conf['proxy_password'] = 'mypass';
$conf['proxy_exceptions'] = array('127.0.0.1', 'localhost');
```

The above configurations working fine as I can check for the updates after setting the proxy.

Why drupal is not sending any emails? How to debug it?

Comment: Do you have sendmail installed on the server? Are you on a shared host?

Comment: To check if your mailserver is generally misconfigured, you can send yourself a password-reset mail. If the mail arrives, your code is buggy. If not, its a mailserver problem.

Comment: Check [Drupal 7 is not sending emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085511/drupal-7-is-not-sending-emails) and [How to debug Drupal not sending email](http://drupalconnect.com/blog/how-debug-drupal-not-sending-email)

Comment: 1. Can you send mail directly for the CLI (e.g. using Gnu/Linux mail)?  2. Can you send mail from PHP outside of Drupal (e.g. using the PHP mail() function).

Comment: Currently I am on Windows 7 with XAMPP installed on my machine. I tried to send password reset mail but couldn't get any mail. I also tried to execute the php mail function on my machine (as listed above also), it shows me mail sent. However I didn't get any mail.

Comment: Ravi, in a situation like this, I'd install the SMTP module and configure it to use an external mail account. It'll be easier than configuring your stack to send mail locally.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong: Thats an interesting suggestion but I wanted to know the reason of it. I suspect on the proxy server. Is it blocking all these mails?

Comment: This is a local configuration issue. Most likely the settings in php.ini.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong: Can you please tell me these settings or refer me to appropriate place please...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending email, you can decide whether to host your own SMTP server or you can use the gmail SMTP server. For both include the SMTP module in your site.. configuration of gmail SMTP server is available here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939238/gmail-smtp-configuration-for-drupal-7
Create a gmail account of yours and use it for your site :)

Comment: How does this answes address the actual question, which is "***Why drupal is not sending any emails? How to debug it?***"?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem following a recent upgrade to the latest version of modules in Drupal 7.

It turned out that following the upgrade I had to use the same email address as the web address, i.e. if the web address is indigoextra.com, you would have to use something@indigoextra.com as the email address that emails are sent from using Mime Mail.

I'm sure this won't always fix the problem, but it's an easy check to make and you can configure this here - /admin/config/system/mimemail